# Ajax request returns 200 but an fail event is fired instead of done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

This is my ajax code, I have given data type as JSON. I receive the success response with code 200, But my ajax fail event is fired.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'API URL',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: JSON.stringify(result)
}).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);         
})
.fail(function(response) {
    console.log("error");
});
```

By the way the response I received is of type JSON only, I have checked the headers.

Comment: how did you checked the headers?

Comment: So you imply that both `done` and `fail` functions are hit?

Comment: As you have set the return data type is JSON, if the return data not in JSON format, it throws error also.

Comment: good point @TheKNVB

Comment: what is response you are getting in `response` object

Comment: Check CORS restrictions. Maybe your API url does not allow everyone to make request

Comment: @Kaushik I checked the headers from the response

Comment: @vahdet No only fail is hit

Comment: @TheKNVB return data is in JSON format only

Comment: @PranavSingh the response is {"key" : "value"}

Comment: For Chrome browser, have you press "F12" and then click the "network" tab to see whether the return value is in correct format?

Comment: Yes!! That is how I tested it

Comment: actually you dont have to use "json.stringify(" when you use dataType JSON and use the full parameters of .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) use console.log() to check textStatus and errorThrown